# Methods to check Fermat' primes with Lucas' primality test

Tags: number-theory

> Lucas' primality test states the following:
> Let $n>1$ an odd number. If for each prime factor $q$ of $n-1$ exists $a>1$ such that
>
> 1. $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$
> 2. $a^{(n-1)/q} \not\equiv 1 \mod n$ 
>    Then $n$ is prime.

My question is if there are a more powerful method than brute-force of applying this test when $n$ is of the form $f_n=2^{2^n}+1$. The only thing that comes to me is that $a+b |a^{2n}-b^{2n}$, wich can eliminate some powers of $a$.